# Using 45W Power Adapter with MacBook Pro Retina 15

Tags: power, display, magsafe

I would like to know if I am able to use a 45W MagSafe Power Adapter in my MacBook Pro Retina 15 with a MagSafe to MagSafe 2 Adapter.

I am normally using the original one (85W MagSafe 2 Power Adapter) but I just want to know that the computer will charge correctly and that the battery won't be hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will charge. However, it will do so very slowly.

Comment: agree - it may, in fact, not keep up if the machine is in heavy use.

Comment: only good for overnight use

Comment: The other thing to bear in mind will be heat - I've used the charger for my 13 inch MacBook with my 15 MPB - it works, but gets very warm. I suspect this will decrease the life of the charger as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the original apple 45W charger from my old MB Air with the magsafe 2 adapter on my MBP 2016 and I haven't had any problems in the last 2.5 years.

Comment: Did you use the 45W on 13' or on a 15' MBP ? Thx

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the MacBook Air 45W power adapter with my MacBook Pro Retina 15" and it works perfectly. Charging takes a little longer than with the original power adapter. I recommend the 45W adapter for travel.